# Unable to find package <local.Package>. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org

Tags: .net-core, nuget, github-actions, github-package-registry

We have developed an API using .Net Core 5. We now wish to deploy that API as a Azure Web App. We use GitHub so opted to integrate deployment of this API with GitHub Actions.

This process seems straight forward enough, however, one of the nuget packages we use has been provided to us via sftp from a third party (we only have the .nupkg files locally on our machines).

If we trigger the build we simply get a lot of errors resembling this:

```
error NU1101: Unable to find package <ThirdParty.Package.Name>. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
```

As the error states it is unable to find the package at "nuget.org", because it does not exist there.

Somehow we need to make these packages available to GitHub Actions build process. I have looked into [GitHub Packages](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry), but do not see how we could get the third party nuget packages into GitHub Packages because we do not have access to the source code, only the .nupkg files.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone running into this, I managed to resolve this by doing the following:

1. In my personal GitHub account, I generated a [Personal Access Token (PAT)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) with package write permissions.
2. I installed [gpr](https://github.com/jcansdale/gpr) onto my machine:
   `dotnet tool install gpr -g`
3. Pushed the package to GitHub:

```
gpr push ".\path-to-package\Packge.Name.1.1.1.nupkg" -r https://github.com/UsernameOrOrganization/repo-name -k <Your PAT>
```